# How to combine unique words when using pandas groupby-count on a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame of dates, ID number, and ingredients (see example below). I have been successful at grouping the ingredients based on ID number, removing duplicates, and counting the unique number of ingredients per ID number as a function of time. However, I would like the option to combine ingredients into a single category instead of separate ones.  For example, instead of outputting: Apples 2, Pears 3, I would get something like: Fruit 5.

This is my example data:

| Date | ID Number | Ingredient |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2022 | 1 | Apple |
| 01-01-2022 | 1 | Apple |
| 01-01-2022 | 1 | Pear |
| 01-01-2022 | 1 | Beef |
| 01-03-2022 | 2 | Apple |
| 01-04-2022 | 3 | Apple |
| 01-04-2022 | 3 | Beef |
| 01-04-2022 | 3 | Beef |
| 01-04-2022 | 4 | Pear |

My code currently is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re
import datetime as dt
import glob
import os
from pathlib import Path
import openpyxl
import xlsxwriter

path2 = "/Users/ProjectPath"
df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f) for f in Path(path2).rglob('*.xlsx')])
df = df[["Date", "ID Number", "Ingredient"]]

df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
mask = (df["Date"] > "2022-01-01") & (df["Date"] <= "2022-12-31")
df22 = df.loc[mask]

df_Example1 = df22
df_Example1["Ingredient"] = df_Example1["Chemical"].str.lower()
df_Example1["Ingredient"].replace(" ", np.nan, inplace=True)
df_Example1 = df_Example1.drop_duplicates(subset=["ID Number", "Ingredient"], keep="first")

df_Example2 = df_Example1.groupby("Ingredient")["ID Number"].count().sort_values(ascending=False).to_frame("Count").reset_index()
df_Example3 = df_Example2[df_Example2["Count"] >0]
print(df_Example3)
```

This gives me the following output for the above dataset

|  | Ingredient | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Apple | 3 |
| 1 | Pear | 2 |
| 2 | Beef | 2 |

The output I would like to be able to get is:

|  | Ingredient | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Fruit | 4 |
| 1 | Beef | 2 |

The Apple and Pear are combined but still only counted once per ID number. And changing the name from Apple/Pear to Fruit.

I think I can do this either right before or right after the line using groupby but I have not had any luck so far.

Any help with how to code this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary to replace your terms and aggregate after dropping the duplicates:

```
d = {'Apple': 'Fruit', 'Pear': 'Fruit'}
(df
 .assign(Ingredient=df['Ingredient'].map(d).fillna(df['Ingredient']))
 .drop_duplicates(['Ingredient', 'ID Number'])
 .groupby('Ingredient', as_index=False).agg(count=('Ingredient', 'count'))
)
```

or:

```
(df
 .assign(Ingredient=df['Ingredient'].map(d).fillna(df['Ingredient']))
 .drop_duplicates(['Ingredient', 'ID Number'])
 ['Ingredient'].value_counts().rename_axis('Ingredient').reset_index(name='count')
)
```

output:

```
  Ingredient  count
0       Beef      2
1      Fruit      4
```

Comment: Thank you for the dictionary idea! Where should this be inserted into my original code? Should it replace any of the code? Also, the word "Ingredient" after the .assign is turning red for me while the word "map" is not turning any colors (using PyCharm).

Comment: I don't use pycharm so I have no idea of the meaning of these colors. You should use the whole code I provided after loading and pre-filtering your data

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, adding your code does nothing to my output. I don't get any errors but the output is the same with or without using this code. I think something is wrong with the mapping but I can't figure it out.

Comment: @SeanS you need to assign the output `out = ...` ;)